# SELECT statement from MS SQL returns dates with loss of 2-4 days

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime

UPD: Solved. I changed DATE fields to DATETIME type in each table. I still have no idea about the "nature" of the problem and why it was so random, but now problem is fixed. Thanks everyone!

I use MS SQL Express 2014 to store some data.
I have 3 different tables, each of them contains a DATE type field.
When I do a select statement to each table via JDBC, the ResultSet in some cases returns dates with loss of 2-4 days.

The code looks like:

```
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    java.sql.Date date = rs.getDate("DATE");
}
```

Dates in DB looks like: "1942-06-10", "1938-03-15", etc. The loss happens only sometimes, no matter how the date looks. On Java side they become "1942-06-08" or "1938-03-11".

I can't understand the reason of the problem, because
in some cases "date" contains the exact data as field in DB,
and in other cases "date" is losing from 2 to 4 days comparing to DB field.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you add example dates from your DB for both cases, along with the result on java side ?

Comment: Just check the timezone for the both DB

Comment: The dates where the loss happens, are they historic dates, say, more than 100 years ago? Does the loss always happen for dates in that range or only sometimes? Do you get the same loss if you try `LocalDate date = rs.getObject("DATE", LocalDate.class)` instead? (The `java.sql.Date` class is outdated and has some design issues to it, so all things being equal I would recommend the latter approach.)

Comment: Dates in DB looks like: "1942-06-10", "1938-03-15", etc. The loss happens only sometimes, no matter how the date looks. On Java side they become "1942-06-08" or "1938-03-11".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is vuja de (never seen it before). Please show your query and a few rows of sample data illustrating the problem. You can [edit] your question to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I changed DATE fields to DATETIME type in each table. I still have no idea about the "nature" of the problem and why it was so random, but now problem is fixed. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.